# Ansible sequential execution of task based on host specified in host file

Tags: ansible

How can I execute the first task for first host 123.345.45.1, whereas for second and third task I need to execute second and third task 2 host onwards but using sequence for instance 123.345.45.2 will need execute 2nd and 3rd task once it it fully complete then should move on to 3rd host 123.345.45.3 to execute 2nd and 3rd task complete. How do I achieve this?

host.yml

```yaml
[server-group-1]
123.345.45.1
123.345.45.2
123.345.45.3
123.345.45.4
123.345.45.5
```

main.yml in role

```yaml
- name: Execute first sh
  shell:"/nityo/execute.sh"

- name: Execute second sh
  shell:"/nityo/script/execute.sh"
  loop: {{ loop_3_times }}

- name: Execute third sh
  shell:"/nityo/bin/execute.sh"
```

Answer (score 1):

The inventory and the playbook below simplified for testing,

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
123.345.45.1
123.345.45.2
123.345.45.3

[server_group_1]
123.345.45.1
123.345.45.2
123.345.45.3
```

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: server_group_1
  serial: 1
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    schedule:
      123.345.45.1: [1]
      123.345.45.2: [2, 3]
      123.345.45.3: [2, 3]
  tasks:
    - name: Task 1
      debug:
        msg: OK
      when: 1 in schedule[inventory_hostname]
    - name: Task 2
      debug:
        msg: OK
      when: 2 in schedule[inventory_hostname]
    - name: Task 3
      debug:
        msg: OK
      when: 3 in schedule[inventory_hostname]
```

should follow the schedule, e.g.

```yaml
PLAY [server_group_1] ***********************

TASK [Task 1] *******************************
ok: [123.345.45.1] => 
  msg: OK

TASK [Task 2] *******************************
skipping: [123.345.45.1]

TASK [Task 3] *******************************
skipping: [123.345.45.1]

PLAY [server_group_1] ***********************

TASK [Task 1] *******************************
skipping: [123.345.45.2]

TASK [Task 2] *******************************
ok: [123.345.45.2] => 
  msg: OK

TASK [Task 3] *******************************
ok: [123.345.45.2] => 
  msg: OK

PLAY [server_group_1] ***********************

TASK [Task 1] *******************************
skipping: [123.345.45.3]

TASK [Task 2] *******************************
ok: [123.345.45.3] => 
  msg: OK

TASK [Task 3] *******************************
ok: [123.345.45.3] => 
  msg: OK
```

Comment: hi the issue with this approach is, sometimes task 2 and 3 need to be executed 1 host at a time meantime some task like task 4 need to be executed in parallel. for instance after task 2 and 3 executed by host A, then task 2 and 3 needed to be executed by host B after that task4 need to be executed by host A followed by host B

Comment: as i research we might use group and include in the play. if u have any idea please share